# Exporting Gridview To Excel Succeeds But File Is Corrupt?

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, openxml, aspnet-development-server

I need to programmatically create an Excel spreadsheet with 3 worksheets.

For Sheet1, I'm trying to Export a Gridview...with all its formatting...and doing it without using Http.Response, because that technique forces a file 'Save/Save As' requester box to pop up and that seems to halt all further code execution.

If I can succeed in directly writing my Gridview to an Excel Workbook, I should be able to continue my coding routine to then re-open the file and programmatically add Sheets 2 and 3.

This code works...kinda'...almost!

```
private void ExportGridView(GridView myGrid)
{
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    // Render grid view control.
    myGrid.RenderControl(htw);

    // Write the rendered content to a file.
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();

    File.WriteAllText("C:\\TimeSheets\\ExportedFile.xlsx", renderedGridView);

}
```

If I stop coding...and navigate to the TimeSheets Directory, I see the "ExportedFile.xlsx" displayed as "Microsoft Office Excel 2007 Workbook" and my Excel program has no problem opening and displaying my properly formatted Gridview.

But if I continue coding in C# and attempt to open that same file in my code-behind, I'm given a 'File contains corrupted data' error.

If, while using Excel to view the "ExportedFile.xlsx" file, I perform a "Save As", I see the filename is placed in quotes and the file type  has defaulted to Save As Webpage htm/html. If I reset those values by removing the quotes from the filename and by setting the file type to ".xlsx"...then, THAT resulting file CAN be read in my code-behind without griping.

Can anyone offer me a solution?

Joe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly you "attempt to open that same file in my code-behind", but if you're trying to open it as an actual excel file that may be your issue.

When you save it 'as an excel file' using HtmlTextWriter you're actually saving it as an html file that excel can read. Try changing the extension to .html and opening it in your browser and you'll see what I mean. That's why excel defaults to 'save as webpage' because that's what it was opened as.

So if your load code treats it like an excel file, that's why you'll have issues. You didn't post any load code so it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Can't just dump gridview into xlsx file and expect it to work.
Need either custom wrapper that uses OpenXml to generate the file or use external lib e.g. http://epplus.codeplex.com/